# How do I get UICollectionView to continuously scroll horizontally instead of creating a second row?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

What is the correct way to adjust the width of the UICollectionView to match the number of cells * their width in order to prevent the UICollectionView from creating a second row in my horizontal collection view.

Is there a specific method to implement for the CollectionView which allows me to set this?

Currently looks like:

[image: 2 Rows, only 1 wanted with full height]

Currently, I'm implementing the following methods:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView)

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int)

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: If you set a fixed height for collectionview which only one row can fit in vertically then you will have single row scrollable horizontal collectionview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first set your collectionView FlowLayout scrollDirection to horizontal.

```
let myColl:UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    let coll = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    return coll
}()
```

then Set your collectionview height constraint equal (or little bit grater) to the cell height

```
myColl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
```

set your cell size in here

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width-32, height: 50)
    }
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, Dilan's answer also works with UICollectionView's that were created and linked using Storyboards.

Simply do what Dilan suggested in your viewDidLoad() function.

```
override func viewDidLoad() { myColl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true }
```

Make sure your class (if not a UICollectionViewController already) subclasses UICollectionViewFlowDelegate.

```
class MyClass: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {}
```

If this is not done,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width-32, height: 50)
}
```

will not be called.